# Usb live camera microphone does not record audio

Tags: sound, soundcard, audio-recording

I tried to record video+audio, using cheese. Video was recorded, audio - not.
I tried to fix:

1. Running `alsamixer -c1` and rasing the volume to 100%
2. Opening pavucontrol and setting corner right to 0, corner left to 100%
   All did not work: if I am recording an audio I can hear only noise in my speakers' output then.

Here is the output of `pacmd list-cards`:

```
2 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_Live_camera_SN0001-02>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "USB Live camera"
    alsa.long_card_name = "Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB Live camera at usb-0000:00:14.0-1.4, high speed"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1.4:1.2"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.2/sound/card1"
    udev.id = "usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_Live_camera_SN0001-02"
    device.bus = "usb"
    device.vendor.id = "0c46"
    device.vendor.name = "WaveRider Communications, Inc."
    device.product.id = "64ab"
    device.product.name = "USB Live camera "
    device.serial = "Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_Live_camera_SN0001"
    device.form_factor = "webcam"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "USB Live camera "
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
    input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (priority 55, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <input:analog-stereo>
sources:
    alsa_input.usb-Sonix_Technology_Co.__Ltd._USB_Live_camera_SN0001-02.analog-stereo/#4: USB Live camera  Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:
            
index: 1
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 8
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xd0810000 irq 97"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "0f04"
    device.product.name = "Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 60, available: no)
    output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
    output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
    output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
ports:
    analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Comment: I went to "capture" in alsamixer and set "capture" to 100% - did not help. "input devices" in pavucontrol="usb live camera Analog stereo, microphone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a somikon camera (Webcam USB HD SXGA, https://www.somikon.fr/produit/webcam-usb-hd-sxga-a-6-led/ ), which was apparently linked to not enough USB bandwith. I was lucky enough to be able to solve the problem simply by plugging it to a different USB port with higher bandwith port (USB 3.0 instead of USB 2.0). However, if it is not the case for you, there is apparently a way to force a limit on the USB bandwith used by the camera to keep some available for the microphone, see
https://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#footnote-13

I still have some minor problem with the microphone because the recorded audio includes some quite heavy background noise. Not sure if related to this issue, and will let you know if I manage to fix it!

Comment: USB 3.0 instead of USB 2.0

Answer (score 1):

In Alsamixer, go to "capture " settings pressing F4 .

In  pavucontrol, did you look in "input devices" tab ?

Comment: I went to "capture" in alsamixer and set "capture" to 100% - did not help. "input devices" in pavucontrol="usb live camera Analog stereo, microphone".